# element.typeahead not defined in angular-typeahead directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typeahead.js, angular-template

I have posted the issue in the source github issues page

https://github.com/Siyfion/angular-typeahead/issues/84

but was wondering if I could find a quicker resolution here.

I am following the loading dependencies, namely jQuery, Angular, and typeahead (bundle), by placing them ahead in my index.html file of the angular-typeahead directive.

Yet I get an error in my Angular template when I include the directive as a class.  I have wrapped the controller code in a document ready function and that did not resolve it.  I am able to type $("input").typeaway in the browser console, and it is eventually defined.  Adding a timeout wrapper in the typeaway source directive code didn't resolve this timing issue.  Any thoughts?

Can I dynamically assign the directive using pure jQuery in my controller and have the scope refresh?  Simply adding the class "sfTypeahead" and then $scope.$apply() did nothing but add the class.

Thanks - any ideas would be MUCH appreciated.

Comment: Are you including the typeahead module in your app module?

Comment: Yes I did.  I resolved this by switching to typeahead.js!